# Does the Dhamma suggest to change external unfavourable conditions

Tags: reference-request, right-intention, right-action

In modern society most politicians and banks are corrupt and only care to gain more money & power. They do not care about the welfare of the citizens. What would the dhammic response be? Activism and Dhamma should be incorporated or not or partially?

Comment: See also [Did the Buddha try to effect social change?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9405/254)

Answer (score 1):

The Buddha did not intend monks to participate in politics, as seen in [DN 2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.02.0.than.html):

> "Whereas some brahmans and contemplatives, living off food given in
>   faith, are addicted to talking about lowly topics such as these —
>   talking about kings, robbers, ministers of state; armies, alarms, and
>   battles; food and drink; clothing, furniture, garlands, and scents;
>   relatives; vehicles; villages, towns, cities, the countryside; women
>   and heroes; the gossip of the street and the well; tales of the dead;
>   tales of diversity [philosophical discussions of the past and future],
>   the creation of the world and of the sea, and talk of whether things
>   exist or not — he abstains from talking about lowly topics such as
>   these. This, too, is part of his virtue.

However, the Buddha did intend for lay people to participate in constructive nation building, in accordance with the Dhamma in [DN 16](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.16.1-6.vaji.html):

> At that time the Venerable Ananda was standing behind the Blessed One, fanning him, and the Blessed One addressed the Venerable
>   Ananda thus: "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis have frequent
>   gatherings, and are their meetings well attended?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that this is so."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline.
>
> "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis assemble and disperse
>   peacefully and attend to their affairs in concord?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that they do."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline.
>
> "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis neither enact new decrees
>   nor abolish existing ones, but proceed in accordance with their
>   ancient constitutions?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that they do."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline.
>
> "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis show respect, honor,
>   esteem, and veneration towards their elders and think it worthwhile to
>   listen to them?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that they do."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline.
>
> "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis refrain from abducting
>   women and maidens of good families and from detaining them?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that they refrain from doing so."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline.
>
> "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis show respect, honor,
>   esteem, and veneration towards their shrines, both those within the
>   city and those outside it, and do not deprive them of the due
>   offerings as given and made to them formerly?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that they do venerate their shrines, and that
>   they do not deprive them of their offerings."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline.
>
> "What have you heard, Ananda: do the Vajjis duly protect and guard the
>   arahats, so that those who have not come to the realm yet might do so,
>   and those who have already come might live there in peace?"
>
> "I have heard, Lord, that they do."
>
> "So long, Ananda, as this is the case, the growth of the Vajjis is to
>   be expected, not their decline."

Answer (score 0):

Lord buddha didn't refuse economical and physical development of a person while he practices dhamma..By reading [Kutadanta Sutta](http://buddhasutra.com/files/kutadanta_sutta.htm) and  [Vyagghapajja Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.054.nara.html)you can get a comprehension on these things..
And otherwise for politicians can refer [saptha aparihai dharma](http://www.dailymirror.lk/article/Seven-Conditions-of-Welfare-Sapta-Aparihani-Dhamma--112710.html)   and [dasa raja dharma](http://www.ibiblio.org/obl/docs/dasajajadhamma.htm),in order to understand their duty